# Static contents are not able to deploy in MAGENTO 2.2.0

Tags: magento2, nginx, magento2.2.0

Static contents are not able to deploy in MAGENTO 2.2.0
I have downloaded default setup of magento 2.2.0 and configured using NGINX.
After deployment static content are not loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Nginx config file with this much content:
```

use this document link: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html

I have tested on magento 2.2.0 ,nginx and os Ubuntu 16.04

```
 upstream fastcgi_backend {
        server  unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    server {

        listen 80;
        server_name www.magento-dev.com;
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento2;
        include /var/www/html/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
    }
```